# How do I create a method for deep cloning a usercontrol

Tags: c#

I would like to create a deep clone of a usercontrol in my program. How do this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `MemberwiseClone()` you will get a shallow copy which is probably not what you want as it will not be a true "replica".  If you don't mind the two `UserControls` sharing references to child objects then `MemberwiseClone()` should do the trick.  Otherwise you will have to write your own implementation to support your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is correct. If you want to do a deep clone, you'll need to add a method to your usercontrol that returns a deep clone.

This gets annoying, because you then need to call this Deep Clone method on each reference type within your usercontrol and so-on.

The IClonable interface was supposed to facilitate this pattern, but it was completely bungled and is largely useless.